# connection to mysql function error in python

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, function, pyodbc

Please bear with me I am a python and programming noob,
I am writing a function to connect to a mysql database

```
server = "localhost"
dbname = "db"
dbuser = "root"
dbpassword = "Klingon"
port = "3399"
driver = "{MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver}"


def mysql_cnxn(driver, serverip, port, dbname, dbuser, dbpassword):

conns = "{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5}".format(driver, serverip, port, dbname, dbuser, dbpassword)

conn = pyodbc.connect(conns)
return conn

mysql_cnxn(driver, serverip, port, dbname, dbuser, dbpassword)
```

I am currently getting the following error:

**pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect); [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid connection string attribute (0)')**

I'm sure its how I am calling the function, please help.
I am using python 3.6.4 if that will help.

Comment: open the [ODBC DataSource], make sure Mysql ODBC 5.3 ANSI is in the [Driver] tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you print the value of `conns` you will see that it looks like

```
{MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver},localhost,3399, ...
```

and that is not a valid ODBC connection string because it is missing the required keywords. It should look like

```
Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver};Server=localhost;Port=3399; ...
```

See the connectionstrings.com page [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/) for details.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation, I implemented it the way you explained and it now works correctly. I'd like to know also how would i get the function to return "true" if the connection was successful or false if not?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "mysql.connector" API to access your database in MySQL. Somes tutorials here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-select.html